# Copying image to clipboard in python in linux

Tags: python, image, copy

Ive tried the gtk method, but it is very slow and doesn't work for a 'large' image (120 kb)

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import os
def copy_image(f):
    assert os.path.exists(f), "file does not exist"
    clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
    img = gtk.Image()
    img.set_from_file(f)
    clipboard.set_image(img.get_pixbuf())
    clipboard.store()
```

Ive tried xclip and it only does text, so what other options are there? What does ubuntu use ?

Comment: "Ubuntu" doesn't use anything, and the applications in Ubuntu might use various programming languages & graphical toolkits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of getting text from/to the clipboard is using [XSel](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/). It's not pretty and requires you to communicate with an external program. But it works and is quite fast.

Not sure if it's the best solution but I know it works :)

[edit]You're right, it seems that `xsel` does not support images.

In that case, how about a slightly modified `GTK` version.

```
def copy_image(f):
    assert os.path.exists(f), "file does not exist"
    image = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(f)

    clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
    clipboard.set_image(image)
    clipboard.store()
```

Do note that you might have to change the owner if your program exits right away because of how X keeps track of the clipboard.

Comment: doesnt seem to paste images... only text

Comment: @josh: it seems you are right, I have added an alternative method which is a bit faster.

Comment: Thanks! Works faster, however this is weird, it seems to work great for pasting into gimp but when pasting into gnumeric or openoffice spreadsheet, it wont paste! Huh...  Any ideas?

Comment: @Josh: Just guessing here, but perhaps OpenOffice and Gnumeric aren't able to figure out the image type? Have you tried other image types (png/bmp) aswell?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the [`set_with_data`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkclipboard.html#method-gtkclipboard--set-with-data) method instead, but that's slightly more work (the image data is only sent when an application requests it, so it needs callback-functions).  This has also advantages when you paste in the same application instead of to another application.