# Why the image is not in the clipboard

Tags: python, pygtk, clipboard

I used this `Python` [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571855/pasting-image-to-clipboard-in-python-in-linux) (inspired here)

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import os
import sys

def copy_image(f):
    assert os.path.exists(f), "file does not exist"
    image = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(f)

    clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
    clipboard.set_image(image)
    clipboard.store()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  copy_image(sys.argv[1])
```

to copy an image to clipboard.
After running

`python imgclip.py img.png`

I'd like to paste the image to `Inkscape` with <kbd>ctrl+V</kbd>, but `Inkscape` writes
`Nothing on the clipboard`.

Do you know how to correct this to be able to copy the image to the clipboard and then paste it to `Inkscape`?

OS: `Ubuntu 12.04`

Comment: From the question you link to: "Do note that you might have to change the owner if your program exits right away because of how X keeps track of the clipboard." I don't know how to change the owner, but I suspect that's what you need.

Comment: You mean to "change the owner of the image file"? I could use `chown` command but don't know the name of the new owner.

Comment: No, I don't think it's the file. As I understand it (which isn't very well), your program 'owns' the clipboard contents, and when it exits, the contents are cleared.

Comment: Your code is not at fault.  Under Linux, the contents are cleared when the program exits, unless a clipboard manager is running to persist it.  On my system, Fedora 14, the image persists on the clipboard just fine.  I'm surprised Ubuntu is not running a clipboard manager by default.